# What is Reaction time method?

Tags: fmri, reaction-time

I'm having some trouble with understanding Reaction Time (RT) method.

I have a hypothesis that M occurs at B where M is a mental activity and B is a location in the brain.  To verify it, I want to use either method subtraction method or mental chronometric (here I say RT). Using fMRI and subtraction method, I think it can be done. For example, suppose that sequence of metal activities A-N-M occurs. Then, by using fMRI, where M occurs and subtract places which are activated when A and N occur.

But designing experiment using the RT, How can I do that where M occurs in brain?

Comment: I edit my question, hope that it helps you grasp what my question is.

Comment: The subtraction method uses RTs to estimate how long it takes to perform two tasks. Then, if you compare the joint RT with the RTs to both tasks individually, you can estimate how much the tasks interfere with eachother. A variable you can play with (and search for) is Stimulus Onset Asynchrony. I will try to formulate a proper answer soon

Comment: @RobinKramer - thanks for stepping in, I'll remove my comments. Could you also clarify the question a bit once you are up to it?

Comment: Hi Daae-Uri, I wanted to start answering your question but the more I read it the more confused I got. If you are asking about some sort of subtraction of brain activity, another question may be related: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/17181/why-the-brain-region-with-less-activity-is-not-more-responsible-for-some-action. Alternatively, if you are interested in [Donder's method of subtraction](http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/harnad/Hypermail/Explaining.Mind/0210.html), could you clarify that into your question?